# Property 'children' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ children: any; }

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm attempting to learn react using a couple different sources and something isn't working in the example.

> Property 'children' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{
> children: any; }

```
export default function Layout({ children }) {  return (
<div>
             {children}
```

I believe it is because I used typescript in my last example.  Does anyone know how to fix this error?  Do I have to know the type of children coming into this layout? If so, how do I handle this?

Comment: This warning is telling you that this particular data structure named ```type``` is supposed to contain a member ```children``` with some acceptable value; but either you haven't provided it properly, or at some point it has gained a ```NULL``` value and that particular interface does not accept that as a ```children``` input.
If the interpreter provided a line number, one could trace back to it and figure out which step the mishandling has occured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good to use `React.FC` type which automatically types your components including your props (by `generic`) and children props.

```
import React from 'react'

const Layout: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Layout
```

```
import React from 'react'
import Layout from './somewhere/Layout'

const MyPageComp: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      hello~ I'm children of Layout Component
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default MyPageComp
```

Comment: thank you, this is what I was missing from the first example I used

Answer (score 1):

According to [HERE](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/function_components), React.FC should be avoided.

The best way is to properly specify the types with:

```
type LayoutProps = {
  children: React.ReactNode
}

export default function Layout({ children }: LayoutProps) {
  return <div>{children}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, error was in Navigation Container, solved it using:

```
<NavigationContainer
      children={
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={Home}
            options={{ title: "Trendings Products" }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Details"
            component={Detail}
            options={{ title: "Product Details" }}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      }
    />
```